# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, linq

I am on a C# ASP.NET project.

I have a MySQL table with a userid field of type `int`.

Now I want to get the number of rows where value of userid equals certain value using LINQ.

To achieve this, I wrote the following method:

```
public int getCount(int usercode) {
    int count = 0;
    DataTable mytable = getAllRowsAndReturnAsDataTable(); // assigning a DataTable value to mytable. 
    if (mytable.Rows.Count > 0) { 
        count = (from x in mytable.AsEnumerable() where x.Field<Int32>("userid") == usercode select x).Count();
    } 
    return count;
}
```

but it is showing error `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` showing `count = (from x in mytable.AsEnumerable() where x.Field<Int32>("userid") == usercode select x).Count();` in red highlight area.

I don't know what I did wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most likely cause of the `InvalidCastException` is the `x.Field<Int32>("userid")` line.  The `Field<T>` extension method will throw an `InvalidCastException` in the case where the actual type of the data doesn't match the type which was passed to `Field<T>`.  Hence if `userid` wasn't an `Int32` this would throw.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments the type of `userid` is actually `UInt32` and not `Int32`.  This is what is causing the problem.  Try using the following and it should work

```
x.Field<UInt32>("userid")
```

Comment: `mysql> desc vticketuser;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idticket     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| userid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
`
this is the field

Comment: @user2168042 you're mixing the DB definition with what the value is when it is managed code.  Try looking at the raw `"userid"` value in the code, call `.GetType` on it and see what type it is being created as

Comment: i dont know am i doing it right .. but i tried like this 

`string ty = t.Rows[0]["userid"].GetType().ToString();`

and it says "System.UInt32"

Comment: #@user2168042 that is the problem then.  The type is `UInt32` which is different than `Int32`.  Use `UInt32` in the `Field<T>` call instead and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the data coming back from your database I can only guess that the following part of your LINQ is at fault:

```
x.Field<Int32>("userid")
```

Your userid column value probably isn't an int, I would put my money on it being NULL?

**UPDATE**: Can you confirm it's not the Field call that is breaking? Simply change your code to something like this without the Field call:

```
public int getCount(int usercode){
  int count = 0;
  DataTable mytable = getAllRowsAndReturnAsDataTable(); // assigning a DataTable value to mytable. 
  if (mytable.Rows.Count > 0) { 
    count = mytable.AsEnumerable().Count();  // No WHERE function call so no casting.
  } 
  return count;
}
```

You could also inspect what the values are that are returned by mytable.AsEnumerable() in a watch window for example to ensure that everything looks correct. If the code above works then it's the Field call blowing up. Find out which row cannot be cast to an Int32 and go from there.

If it is in fact NULL, there are a number of ways you can solve this.

1. Make sure you don't return NULL from your database query, in MySQL you can use [IFNULL](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php).
2. Use a nullable type for the generic being passed into Field:

   where x.Field("userid") == (Int32?)usercode

Comment: its Int and I am 100% sure. I rechecked it.

Comment: @user2168042 - Updated the answer with some more detail on how to go about finding out if the data is correct and if Field<T> is in fact the issue.